# Global translucency sorting with instanced rendering

Tags: sorting, opengl-es, webgl, rendering, translucency

My rendering code is structured such that there are models, and there are model instances.
You can have N instances per model, and all visible instances of the same model are rendered at the same time with instanced rendering.

This works fine as far as performance goes - my code needs to render hundreds to thousands of instances, each one of them possibly being composed of multiple render calls, and the amount of render/uniform/texture/etc. calls was an issue.

The problem comes when I want to consider instances that use translucency, which in this case is a whole lot of them - in such cases, the order in which they are rendered matters, since the models use various blending functions.
I can sort instances per model, but once there are instances of multiple models being rendered, the order is arbitrary (in practice it is based on the order at which the models were loaded).

I can't for the life of me figure any way to do such global sorting with instanced rendering.

Is this at all possible? Should instanced rendering be used purely for opaque objects?

My code uses WebGL1, which lacks so many modern features, but I'll be interested to know if this is possible, even if only in a more modern API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instancing is ultimately a performance optimization; there is nothing you can render via instancing that you can't do without it. It's simply a matter of how many draw calls you make.

If the order in which different meshes are rendered is important (which with blending, it is), then you cannot use instancing. If you have to draw everything back-to-front in order to make the rendering work out, then that's what you have to do. No matter how many draw calls it takes.

Comment: I had the same thoughts, but I came here for the last hail mary attempt to get some magical solution. In the end I redesigned my code to add capabilities to render opaque stuff using instanced rendering, and non-opaque stuff in sorted per-object draw calls.

Answer (score 2):

If your question is can you sort objects drawn with `gl.drawArraysInstanced` / `gl.drawElementsInstanced` with other things the answer is "No"

If your question is are there other ways to optimize the answer "Yes". It really depends on where your bottleneck is.

For example you can ["pull vertices"](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-pulling-vertices.html) which basically means you put your vertex data in a texture. Once you've done that you now have random access vertices so you can draw models in any order. You'll have to update at least one buffer or texture with model ids and or model vertex offsets but that might be faster than drawing each model with a separate draw call.

[This talk](https://webglsamples.org/google-io/2011/index.html) doesn't use vertex pulling but it does show that updating a buffer for a lot of objects can be much faster than calling draw individually for each one. Whether or not similar techniques fit your use case is up to you

Here's an example. It puts the data for 4 models (cube, sphere, cylinder, torus) into a texture (vertexDataTexture). It then puts data for each object to be drawn into a separate texture (perObjectDataTexture). Think of these as the uniforms. In this case there is a model matrix and a color per object.

perObjectDataTexture is updated once per frame with all the uniform like data.

It only has 1 attribute called `perVertexData`. For each vertex there is a vertexId (which vertex to use, used to get the vertex data from the vertexDataTexture) and an objectId, used to get the per object data from perObjectDataTexture.

The buffer for that attribute has to be filled out every frame if you want to change the sorting order.

The result is drawing 2000 independent objects from 4 different models in 1 draw call. Effectively we made our own instancing that is more flexible than standard instancing. Pulling data from textures like this is likely slower than not but 1 draw call and 2 data uploads is likely faster than 2000 draw calls + all the extra calls for uniforms (though I didn't test so maybe it's slower)

```js
const m4 = twgl.m4;
const v3 = twgl.v3;
const gl = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('webgl');
const ext = gl.getExtension('OES_texture_float');
if (!ext) {
  alert('need OES_texture_float');
}

const COMMON_STUFF = `
#define TEXTURE_WIDTH 5.0
#define MATRIX_ROW_0_OFFSET ((0. + 0.5) / TEXTURE_WIDTH)
#define MATRIX_ROW_1_OFFSET ((1. + 0.5) / TEXTURE_WIDTH)
#define MATRIX_ROW_2_OFFSET ((2. + 0.5) / TEXTURE_WIDTH)
#define MATRIX_ROW_3_OFFSET ((3. + 0.5) / TEXTURE_WIDTH)
#define COLOR_OFFSET        ((4. + 0.5) / TEXTURE_WIDTH)
`;

const vs = `
attribute vec2 perVertexData;

uniform float perObjectDataTextureHeight;  // NOTE: in WebGL2 use textureSize()
uniform sampler2D perObjectDataTexture;

uniform vec2 vertexDataTextureSize;  // NOTE: in WebGL2 use textureSize()
uniform sampler2D vertexDataTexture;

uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;

varying vec3 v_normal;
varying float v_objectId;

${COMMON_STUFF}

void main() {
  float vertexId = perVertexData.x;
 float objectId = perVertexData.y;

  v_objectId = objectId;  // pass to fragment shader

  float objectOffset = (objectId + 0.5) / perObjectDataTextureHeight;

  // note: in WebGL2 better to use texelFetch
  mat4 model = mat4(
    texture2D(perObjectDataTexture, vec2(MATRIX_ROW_0_OFFSET, objectOffset)),
    texture2D(perObjectDataTexture, vec2(MATRIX_ROW_1_OFFSET, objectOffset)),
    texture2D(perObjectDataTexture, vec2(MATRIX_ROW_2_OFFSET, objectOffset)),
    texture2D(perObjectDataTexture, vec2(MATRIX_ROW_3_OFFSET, objectOffset)));
    
  
  // note: in WebGL2 better to use texelFetch
  // note: vertexId will be even numbers since there are 2 pieces of data
  //       per vertex, position and normal.
  vec2 colRow = vec2(mod(vertexId, vertexDataTextureSize.x),
                     floor(vertexId / vertexDataTextureSize.x)) + 0.5;
  vec2 baseUV = colRow / vertexDataTextureSize;
  vec4 position = texture2D(vertexDataTexture, baseUV);
  vec3 normal = texture2D(vertexDataTexture, baseUV + vec2(1) / vertexDataTextureSize).xyz;
  
  gl_Position = projection * view * model * position;
  v_normal = mat3(view) * mat3(model) * normal;
}
`;

const fs = `
precision highp float;

varying vec3 v_normal;
varying float v_objectId;

uniform float perObjectDataTextureHeight;
uniform sampler2D perObjectDataTexture;
uniform vec3 lightDirection;

${COMMON_STUFF}

void main() {
  float objectOffset = (v_objectId + 0.5) / perObjectDataTextureHeight;

  // maybe we should look this up in the vertex shader
  vec4 color = texture2D(perObjectDataTexture, vec2(COLOR_OFFSET, objectOffset));
  
  float l = dot(lightDirection, normalize(v_normal)) * .5 + .5;
  
  gl_FragColor = vec4(color.rgb * l, color.a);
}
`;

// compile shader, link, look up locations
const programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);

// make some vertex data
const modelVerts = [
  twgl.primitives.createSphereVertices(1, 6, 4),
  twgl.primitives.createCubeVertices(1, 1, 1),
  twgl.primitives.createCylinderVertices(1, 1, 10, 1),
  twgl.primitives.createTorusVertices(1, .2, 16, 8),
].map(twgl.primitives.deindexVertices);
const modelVertexCounts = [];
const modelVertexOffsets = [];
{
 let offset = 0;
  modelVerts.forEach((verts) => {
    let vertexCount = verts.position.length / 3;
    modelVertexCounts.push(vertexCount);
    modelVertexOffsets.push(offset);
    offset += vertexCount;  
  });
}
// merge all the vertices into one
const arrays = twgl.primitives.concatVertices(modelVerts);

// copy arrays into texture.
function copyPositionsAndNormalsIntoTexture(arrays) {
  const maxTextureSize = gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE);
  const numVerts = arrays.position.length / 3;
  const numPixels = numVerts * 2;  // each vertex will have position and normal
  const numPixelsNeeded = ((numPixels + maxTextureSize - 1) / maxTextureSize | 0) * maxTextureSize;
  const data = new Float32Array(numPixelsNeeded * 4); // RGBA
  for (let i = 0; i < numVerts; ++i) {
    const src = i * 3;
  const dst = i * 2 * 4;
  data[dst    ] = arrays.position[src    ];
  data[dst + 1] = arrays.position[src + 1];
  data[dst + 2] = arrays.position[src + 2];
    data[dst + 3] = 1;
  data[dst + 4] = arrays.normal[src    ];
  data[dst + 5] = arrays.normal[src + 1];
  data[dst + 6] = arrays.normal[src + 2];
    data[dst + 7] = 1;
  }
  const height = numPixelsNeeded / maxTextureSize;
  const texture = gl.createTexture();
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, texture);
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, maxTextureSize, height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, data);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
  return {
    texture,
    size: [maxTextureSize, height],
  };
}

const vertexDataTextureInfo = copyPositionsAndNormalsIntoTexture(arrays);

let numTotalVerts = 0;
const numObjects = 2000;
const objects = [];
for (let i = 0; i < numObjects; ++i) {
  const modelId = r() * modelVerts.length | 0; 
  numTotalVerts += modelVertexCounts[modelId];
  objects.push({
    modelId,
    objectId: i,
  });
}

// for every vertex we need 2 pieces of data
// 1. An objectId (used to look up per object data)
// 2. An vertexID (used to look up the vertex)
const perVertexData = new Uint16Array(numTotalVerts * 2);
// calls gl.createBuffer, gl.bindBuffer, gl.bufferData
const bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, {
  perVertexData: {
   numComponents: 2,
    data: perVertexData,
  },
});

const perObjectDataTexture = gl.createTexture();
const perObjectDataTextureWidth = 5; // 4x4 matrix, 4x1 color
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, perObjectDataTexture);
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, perObjectDataTextureWidth, numObjects, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, null);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, gl.NEAREST);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
gl.texParameteri(gl.TEXTURE_2D, gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

// this data is for the texture, one row per model
// first 4 pixels are the model matrix, 5 pixel is the color
const perObjectData = new Float32Array(perObjectDataTextureWidth * numObjects * 4);
const stride = perObjectDataTextureWidth * 4;
const modelOffset = 0;
const colorOffset = 16;

// set the colors at init time
for (let objectId = 0; objectId < numObjects; ++objectId) {
  perObjectData.set([r(), r(), r(), 1], objectId * stride + colorOffset);
}

function r() {
  return Math.random();
}

const RANDOM_RANGE = Math.pow(2, 32);
let seed = 0;
function pseudoRandom() {
  return (seed =
          (134775813 * seed + 1) %
          RANDOM_RANGE) / RANDOM_RANGE;
}

function resetPseudoRandom() {
  seed = 0;
}


function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;  // seconds
  
  twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
  
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
  gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
  gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);

  const fov = Math.PI * 0.25;
  const aspect = gl.canvas.clientWidth / gl.canvas.clientHeight;
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 20;
  const projection = m4.perspective(fov, aspect, near, far);
  
  const eye = [0, 0, 15];
  const target = [0, 0, 0];
  const up = [0, 1, 0];
  const camera = m4.lookAt(eye, target, up);
  const view = m4.inverse(camera);

  // set the matrix for each object in the texture data
  resetPseudoRandom();
  const mat = m4.identity();
  for (let objectId = 0; objectId < numObjects; ++objectId) {
    // of course you'd probably store translation, rotation, etc per object in objects[]
    const t = time * (0.3 + pseudoRandom() * 0.1) + pseudoRandom() * Math.PI * 2;
    
    m4.identity(mat);
    m4.rotateX(mat, t * 0.93, mat);
    m4.rotateY(mat, t * 0.87, mat);
    m4.translate(mat, [
      1 + pseudoRandom() * 3,
      1 + pseudoRandom() * 3,
      1 + pseudoRandom() * 3,
    ], mat);
    m4.rotateZ(mat, t * 1.17, mat);
    
    perObjectData.set(mat, objectId * stride);
  }
  
  // set the per vertex data. (sort objects before this line)
  {
    let offset = 0;
    for (const obj of objects) {
     const numVerts = modelVertexCounts[obj.modelId];
      const vertOffset = modelVertexOffsets[obj.modelId];
      for (let v = 0; v < numVerts; ++v) {
       perVertexData[offset++] = (vertOffset + v) * 2;  // 2 is because 2 pixels per vertex, one for position, one for normal
        perVertexData[offset++] = obj.objectId; 
      }
    }
  }
  // upload the per vertex data
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, bufferInfo.attribs.perVertexData.buffer);
  gl.bufferSubData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, perVertexData);
  
  // upload the texture data
  gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, perObjectDataTexture);
  gl.texSubImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, perObjectDataTextureWidth, numObjects, 
                   gl.RGBA, gl.FLOAT, perObjectData);
  
  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  
  // calls gl.bindBuffer, gl.enableVertexAttribArray, gl.vertexAttribPointer
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
  
  // calls gl.activeTexture, gl.bindTexture, gl.uniformXXX
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, {
    lightDirection: v3.normalize([1, 2, 3]),
    perObjectDataTexture,
    perObjectDataTextureHeight: numObjects,
    vertexDataTexture: vertexDataTextureInfo.texture,
    vertexDataTextureSize: vertexDataTextureInfo.size,
    projection,
    view,
  });  
  
  // calls gl.drawArrays or gl.drawElements
  twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, bufferInfo);

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/4.x/twgl-full.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

A few notes:

- I was lazy and made the perObjectDataTexture just be one row per object. That means you can have at most `gl.getParameter(gl.MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE)` objects. To fix you need to change how the per object data is stored in the texture and then fix the shaders uv math to find the data how you arranged it
- I'm looking up the color in the fragment shader instead of pass it in from the vertex shader. There's a limited number of varyings. I think 8 is in general the minimum available. It would arguably be good to use those rather than just pass the objectId and doing all that math in the fragment shader.

Comment: That is an interesting idea. I already store bone matrices in a texture since they need random access, didn't think about doing the same with vertices. That being said, for my specific case I think the models might be a bit too big and complex for this. I will have to test the idea, thanks!